# How to randomize the case of letters in a string in Swift?

Tags: string, swift

Given a string, I would like to change the case of each letter to a random between upper and lower case.

For example:

```
let myString = "Have a nice day!"
let newString = "haVe A NiCe dAY!"
```

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary to reproduce it* in the question itself. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Swift 2**

I would use `arc4random_uniform` and `map`.

```
let myString = "Have a nice day!"

let result = myString.characters.map { (char) -> String in
    if arc4random_uniform(2) == 0 {
        return String(char).lowercaseString
    }
    return String(char).uppercaseString
}.joinWithSeparator("")

print(result)
```

> hAvE A NICe DAy!

**Swift 3**:

```
let result = myString.characters.map {
    if arc4random_uniform(2) == 0 {
        return String($0).lowercased()
    }
    return String($0).uppercased()
}.joined(separator: "")
```

**Swift 4.2**

```
let result = myString.map {
    if Int.random(in: 0...1) == 0 {
        return String($0).lowercased()
    }
    return String($0).uppercased()
}.joined(separator: "")
```

Comment: THank YoU anD HAve A NICe DAy EriC!